# Data Annotations or jQuery for validations in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can you advise which is the better way to handle data validations in MVC4 between data annotations validators and jQuery validations or any other way which I dont know ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: with data annotations ull have to code less...and with jQuery ull have to code a little more for the validations but ull have good control on the UI..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all take a look at this :

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
public class Album
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int      AlbumId    { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Genre")]
    public int      GenreId    { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Artist")]
    public int      ArtistId   { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Album Title is required")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string   Title      { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
    [Range(0.01, 100.00,
        ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 0.01 and 100.00")]
    public decimal Price       { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Album Art URL")]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual Genre  Genre    { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist   { get; set; }
}
}
```

Its so easy to write validation by using data annotation. But, if you want to do that with jquery you have to manually write all of the codes yourself. Thats all!

And, it supports all type of client side validation :

- Required
- StringLength
- Range  etc...

Answer (score 0):

Adding some More Information to above Answer you can also write custom validation rule at Server Side by adding Remote Validation Attribute.

The Request would be Async to the server without loading the Web page.